# Ovalbox with fixed corner diameter

Tags: boxes

I wish to use `\Ovalbox` with a fix corner diameter.
How can it be done?

The problem is when I got a lot of text in the box, the corners run over the text.

Comment: `\Ovalbox` is in which packages? fancybox perhaps ?

Comment: Do you have a minimal example to show what you want or where is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry my english is not good enough. You want a fix corner diameter and not a fix width 
You need \cornersize{.2} perhaps !
Something like this :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\cornersize{.2} 
\ovalbox{$x^n + y^n = z^n$}
\ovalbox{\begin{minipage}{6cm}
This is the first paragraph. We shall go over Fermat theorem.
\[ x^n + y^n = z^n \]
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! What's the default value of `\cornersize`, or how do you reset to the default value? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Run it with `xelatex`or `latex=>dvips=>ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\psset{cornersize=absolute,linearc=.5\baselineskip} 
\psframebox{$x^n + y^n = z^n$}
\psframebox[framesep=2mm,fillcolor=blue!20,
  fillstyle=solid]{\parbox{6cm}{%
This is the first paragraph. We shall go over Fermat theorem.
\[ x^n + y^n = z^n \]}}

\end{document}
```

[image]